# How to create a branch in git basing it on a remote branch

Tags: git

The remote repo has a branch which doesn't exist on the local repo. I need to fetch it and start working with it without merging it with any other branches that I have. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR version

`git fetch remote; git checkout branch`

#### History

The git designers seem to have made this *deliberately* confusing, but actually the confusion is due to the evolutionary path git took.

In the very old days (before git version 1.5) you just grabbed the branch directly off the other repository, typing in the full URL for the repository each time.  As you can probably imagine, typing in long repository paths all the time grew old fast.  There were a bunch of intermediate solutions, then someone came up with the idea of a *remote*: a short name like `origin` you could use to store everything you might like to know about the other git repository.

Along with the remote came *remote-tracking branches*.  The idea here was that if your git calls up another git over the Internet-phone and spends some time chatting with it and retrieves a whole bunch of new stuff, it might be nice to tuck away, in your own repository, a memory of *every* branch they offered you and which commits those were.  These are your remote-tracking branches: `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on.

Whenever you run `git fetch origin` your git phones up their git, picks up any new commits they offer, and squirrels away *all* their branches as `origin/branch`.  If you did not have them before, you do now.

#### Checking out a remote-tracking branch

Now, you *can* check out a remote-tracking branch, but you can't get *on* a remote-tracking branch:

```
$ git checkout origin/develop
```

is exactly like finding the commit ID of `origin/develop`:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/develop
39d22b9678b8c571aab6902620c95907d5bef2db
```

and then handing that to `git checkout`:

```
$ git checkout 39d22b9678b8c571aab6902620c95907d5bef2db
Note: checking out '39d22b9678b8c571aab6902620c95907d5bef2db'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. ...
```

(The only difference is that git can use the name `origin/develop` if you hand that to `git checkout`—you still get that 'detached HEAD' message.)

#### Creating a local branch

`git checkout -b branch` will create and put you on a new local branch, starting from the current commit.  Which is fine, but this means you have to check out the remote-tracking branch first.  Or, you can tell `git checkout -b` where to start the new branch.  But then you should also set it up to track (as git puts it) the other branch, which brings us to:

#### Creating a local branch from a remote-tracking branch

Now, the tricky bit is that once you have `origin/develop` (or some other `origin/`-qualified branch name), you can `git checkout` a regular, ordinary, local branch using that same name, even if you don't have one yet.  Git will notice that `develop` is not (yet) a branch name, so it will scan through all your remote-tracking branches and discover that there's exactly one matching name—`origin/develop` in this case—and assume you meant "please create a new `develop` and make it track `origin/develop` so that it initially starts with the *same* commit that `origin/develop` points to right now".

(This is such a common thing to need that the git folks added it way back in git version 1.6.6.)

#### Wait, a local branch tracks a remote-tracking branch?

Yes.

#### But then why isn't it a local-tracking branch?

There are way too many occurrences of the words "local", "remote", and "tracking" already, not to mention [the multiple meanings of the word "branch"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452).  You want a local-tracking branch to track a remote-tracking branch?  What happens if your local branch tracks **another** *local* branch? :-)  (Yes, git can do that.)

Seriously, the terminology is a little weird.  It just grew like that.

#### A few other things

The `git branch` command has `--set-upstream-to` and `--unset-upstream`.  These operate on the current branch by default, or a local branch if you specify one, and set the name of the *other* branch that the local branch is to track (for `--set-upstream-to`), or stop the local branch from tracking whatever it is set to track (for `--unset-upstream`).  These use the word "upstream" instead of the phrase *remote-tracking branch*, which is reasonable since you can set the upstream to another local branch.  That's how you track the other branch (whether or not it's a remote-tracking branch).

#### What good is having a local branch track some other branch?  Why bother at all?

It lets `git rebase` and `git merge` know what to rebase-on or merge-with so that you don't have to type that in again; and it lets `git status` count commits that you have on the local branch that the other branch doesn't (`ahead 3`, for instance) and/or that they have that you don't (e.g., `behind 12`).  In other words, it's just for convenience.  It *is* pretty convenient though.  It tastes good *and* it's good for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just type:

```
git fetch <remote>
```

to fetch all refs from your remote,

```
git checkout <remote>/<branch>
```

lets you checkout your remotes branch to an "anonymous" branch,

```
git checkout -b <new_local_branch>
```

creates a local branch based on the remote one you checked out.

You can also set the remote branch as upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote/branch> <new_local_branch>
```

Comment: It's not really an anonymous branch.  After all you called it something.  It is a remote tracking branch actually.

Comment: After checking out the remote branch with git checkout <remote>/<branch> I am on an unnamed, "anonymous", branch, I guess.

Comment: After checking our remote/branch you are in detached head.  This is not generally speaking useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `git` expert, but I guess you can switch to the desired branch, pull it, then create the new branch from that.
In other terms:

```
git checkout remote_branch
git pull
git checkout -b new_branch
```

To fetch remote branches, you can use:

```
git fetch remote_name
```

Where *remote_name* is the name of the *remote* in use, as an example *origin*.

Comment: how can I checkout to a branch that doesn't exist localy yet?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. This one command does it:

```
git fetch remote branch_name:branch_name
```

Comment: That does most of the job, but the resulting local branch is not tracking the remote-tracking branch.  In general, the way to do this is `git fetch <remote>` followed by `git checkout <branch>`.  I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This `Git checkout -b new_branch` creates a new branch of name 'new_branch'

`git pull origin remote_branch` pulls code from remote_branch to new_branch

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git pull origin remote_branch
```

Alternatively you can try

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

[referance](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)